# Jquery - Looking for a solution to play audio files

Tags: jquery, audio

My website is about sharing music files and putting it for download.
My main goal is having a audio player on the page to play mp3 files on the page which user desires.

For example let's say this week I post 10 tracks of Eminem music files. There is 10 links of mp3 files, right ? But user is not sure which one he/she will like. So before starting to download all of them, They want to play it first on the same page.

I know they are many flash players which can play a single or playlist. And I know there are Inline players which adds a player to each mp3 link ... etc.

The thing is that I want to have only 1 player on the main page, and when user click the play button on link,not the player itself ===>  ex. Eminem 8 Mile (play) 
The player start playing that link.

So :

- I don't a player pointed to an individual file
- I don't a player pointed to a playlist
- **I do want a player on page which starts playing any clicked mp3 link on the page before refreshing or going to a new link.**

Is there any plugin/script like this ?

Comment: You can try using jPlayer, simple, skinnable and extendible. http://jplayer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is what I did to achieve an inline web player.

As for adding a play button next to each mp3 link, I used a simple .each and .after function to do this. Here is a simple code :

```
$("#Post_Content_Div").find('a[href$="mp3"]').each(function() {
$(this).after('<a class="mp3play" href="javascript:Play(\''+ this.href +'\');"></a>');
});
```

And for the playing function, I used [JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) which has built-in function to play files dynamically in page. Here is a simple code:

```
function Play(url){
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': url,
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'autostart': 'true',
...
}
```

That's it. I was looking for something that works out of box. But there is no such thing. With just a little jQuery, css and javascript code I managed to get this.